# Aggregating data by zip code over time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, aggregation, zip-codes, spatio-temporal-data

I have data that is at the zip code level and I am looking to be able to have that data aggregate over time with a temporal display of the map. Is there a way to do this using QGIS?

Comment: start here https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html